# How to fix "InterfaceError: No result set to fetch" from in python using mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to run a select query in my already populated database through the mysql connector in python, and print the results.

I've checked the query "SELECT * FROM employee" in the mysql console and it works. I could not find an error in my code. Note that I can successfully insert rows into the database(so the credentials are correct). I looked around for a solution, but none of them were my exact problem. Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = "localhost",
            user = "root",
            passwd = "....",
            database = "officeplanning")

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM employee"
mycursor.execute(query)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for row in myresult: print(row)
```

I should be getting a list printed in the console, but instead I am getting the error:

```
File "C:\Users\Anubhab\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 489, in fetchall
    raise errors.InterfaceError("No result set to fetch from.")

InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.
```

Edit: I did not call the fetchall() function twice (which caused the issue in that case) unlike the duplicate suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, mysql.connector Error: No Result Set to Fetch From; cgitb shows correct value being passed to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232426/python-mysql-connector-error-no-result-set-to-fetch-from-cgitb-shows-correct)

Comment: No. In that code, there were two fetchall() calls which caused the problem, on removing which the issue was solved. In my case, I have only one fetchall() call.

Comment: What happens if you replace `print(myresult)` by a loop: `for row in myresult: print(row)`?

Comment: Does not make any difference. The error is in the line "myresult = mycursor.fetchall()" the python interpreter does not go beyond that anyway.

Comment: if you do an insert before the select query, does it work?

Comment: @Anubhabchak Did you find solution for this ?